# How do I maintain aspect ratio of an imageview like in this application? [Android, ImageView, Aspect ratio, ScrollView]

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, imageview

I'd like to achieve the aspect ratio of an imageview and button group as displayed on the picture 1 below. Picture 2 is the current state of my activity. I'd like to achieve the same state as the app in picture 1.

Edit 1 - App on picture one is always imageview + button group, an all devices, so it isn't a matter of aspect ratio, it's something else

The imageview and the button group are wrapped in a constraint layout, which is inside of a scrollview.

Picture 1 - [image]
Picture 2 - [image]

Code below is the part that is regarding the ImageView and button group.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/poster_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/buttons_group"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/poster_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imdb_placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/trailer_button"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/watch_later_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/buttons_group"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/buttons_group"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/watch_later_button"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_watch_later"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/buttons_group"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/buttons_group"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/trailer_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/share_movie_button"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_movie_button"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/buttons_group"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/buttons_group"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/watch_later_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Does the view need to scroll? Are you trying to get the picture to take up the entirety of the screen and allow the buttons to scroll on top?

Comment: Yeah, sort of. The picture and the buttons should take up the screen height, BUT they're inside of a scrollview, so i'd like to scroll down. Any ideas?

Comment: How comfortable are you with RecyclerViews?

Comment: We have a love-hate relationship haha, why? The application I'm referring to is TodoMovieList,

Comment: I know a fairly easy way to accomplish this with Recycler view.

Comment: Any links, or anything else? It's the only thing really "wrong" with my app, and it's really bothering me. If it helps, I have my app on github, not sure if I am allowed to post any links.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `RecyclerView` you can provide multiple view types.

```
enum class ViewType {
    HEADER_CONTROLS,
    ADDITIONAL_CONTROLS,
    COMMENTS
}

class Adapter() {
    fun getViewType(position: Int): Int {
        when (position) {
            0 -> ViewType.HEADER_CONTROLS.ordinal
            // ETC
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create your header view as a match parent and it will scroll appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, tried it. Still didn't get what's on picture 1, same ratio displayed differently on different devices, while the app from picture 1 remains the same on all devices. The top of the scrollview is always imageview+button group

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Should I encapsulate what I want to be in the header view as an recyclerview element? I've never used recyclerview with multiple view types

Comment: You could break it into each view or group whatever feels more comfortable.  I have done both. Either works well.